# Get length of rendered HTML on Rails server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How could I get the length on the server side of of a HTML string after it was rendered.

E.g. `A&amp;B<a href="http://www.abc.org">C</a>` has a length of 4 after it was rendered.

On the client side this would be pretty easy using for example jQuery. Just pack it in a div and call `$("div").text().length`.

But what can I use on the server side using Ruby/Rails?

### Update

I guess Mike is right that there is no direct solution for that. But is there a library that let me easily convert special entities like `&amp;` to the normal presentation (`&`)?

### Update of Update ;-)

I think http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/ will do the trick.

Comment: usually you can use `string.size` to return its length. But you are not clear here. So add some more information

Comment: Do you want to get the same length of 4 from the server-side length?

Comment: I'd like to get the "size" of string how it is presented to the user. The user in his browser does see `A&BC` in the above example, so length == 4 of this rendered html string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this isn't built in as Rails strictly returns the HTML for the browser to parse and render. Rails has no idea how the HTML will be rendered to the user.